# Probability of product of two numbers having a specific property

Tags: probability

Assume that $m$ and $n$ are integers picked completely at random, with $0 \leq m,n \leq 9$.

How do I *calculate* that

$$
\mathrm{Pr}(m \cdot n < 25) = \frac{67}{100}
$$

and not just add up all the possibilities? That is, how do I calculate that there are $67$ possibilities with $m \cdot n < 25$?

**Update**

By using the hint of Gautam Shenoy and the comment of HowDoIMath, I found a general solution: Assume that $m$ and $n$ are integers picked completely at random, with $0 \leq m,n \leq k$. Then

$$
\mathrm{Pr}(m \cdot n < l) = \frac{1}{(k + 1)^{2}} \cdot \sum_{n = 1}^{k}\left(\min(\lfloor l/n\rfloor,k)+2\right)
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Condition on $n=0,1,\cdots 9$. For each value of $n \neq 0$, the valid values $m$ can take are from $0$ to $\min\{\lfloor\frac{25}{n}\rfloor,9\}$. For $n=0$, $m$ can vary of course over all $10$ values.

Comment: That looks like a systematic way of adding up the possibilities

Comment: @GautamShenoy I don't see how this helps me; sorry. Can you elaborate on your hint?

Comment: @Henry I think so too.

Comment: @All: I presumed OP didn't want to enumerate all possibilities and preferred a systematic way of calculating by using a summation etc. Judging by his acceptance of my answer, I'd say he's got it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "calculate". There will be a formula that you can plug into a computer to get the probability, but I suspect that it will be faster for the computer to cleverly check if $m\cdot n<25$ or not.

For $n=0$, check if $m=9$ works. It does, so $(0,m)$ is a solution for all $m$, since the product $m\cdot n$ is increasing in $m$.

Similarly $(1,m)$ and $(2,m)$ work for all $m$.

For $n=3$, you throw $m=9$ away, but $m=8$ works, so $(3,m)$ is a solution for all $m\leq 8$.

For $n=4$, we are down to $m=6$, so $(4,m)$ solves it for $m\leq 6$.

And finally $(5,m)$ solves it for $m\leq 4$.

Since the problem is symmetric in $m$ and $n$, there are no reason to check $n>5$.

If I count correctly, I did only $16$ multiplications, and any formula will probably involve division with remainder and more.

Comment: By calculate I mean (as you correctly guessed) using a formula.

Comment: Then won't Gautam Shenoy's formula work for you? It's $10+\sum_{n=1}^9 \min\{\lfloor\frac{25}{n}\rfloor,9\}$.

Comment: Using your suggested formula (and replacing $10$ by $19$), I get $68$ and not $67$. Shouldn't it be $2 \cdot (9 + 1) - 1 = 19$ and not $2 \cdot 9 = 18$?

Comment: Sorry, I misrepresented the formula. I should have written $10+\sum_{n=1}^9 (\min\{\lfloor\frac{25}{n}\rfloor,9\}+1) = 19+\sum_{n=1}^9 \min\{\lfloor\frac{25}{n}\rfloor,9\},$ as you point out. But it is still off by one. The reason is that the case $n=5$ does work. You should only add $1$, when $n$ does not divide $25$. @SvendTveskæg

Comment: I meant *doesn't work*, of course.